# Sharepoint.WebControls ToolTips

Tags: field-controls, publishing-page

How can I set a tooltip to field controls in edit mode?

For instance when a user edit a article, hovering over TextField (or the title of the field) a tooltip with custom text will show.
It would also be nice to fetch this text from resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the TITLE html attribute for browser-standard tooltips or javascript solutions like jQuery plugins. As a matter of fact, jQuery itself would be helpful for setting the titles of appropriate html elements as well.

Comment: Yeah I see how this would work. But how well does it work with resoures?

Comment: The best way seems to be to first set ID on the field control, then do something like this in jQuery, for Title: $(".ms-formfieldcontainer:has(input[id*=_Title_ctl00])").attr("title", "ToolTip goes here");
Then I get the whole div. Still need to figure out how to feetch from resoruces though